# Use CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH for multi-configuration builds

Tags: qt, cmake

I am using find_package to find Qt and adding "C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\lib\cmake" to my `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` environment variable and it has worked fine when just using 64-bit up until now. However, I want the ability to switch between 32-bit and 64-bit builds. I therefore also added the equivalent above path for 32-bit, however this resulted in linking errors (presumably CMake wasn't sure which one to pick and picked the wrong one for one of the configurations).

What is the conventional way to fix this situation? At the moment I'm using a suffix path and searching in that dependent on the compiler architecture, however ideally I'd like to leave that stuff out of the CMake project itself and simply require users of the project to add whatever Qt location themselves, while still being able to have "more than one" Qt location.

Is this solvable? Or is it malpractice to have two Qt paths in your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the conventional way to fix this situation?**

Only add to your CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH the Qt path corresponding to the architecture you want.

**[...] however ideally I'd like to leave that stuff out of the CMake project itself and simply require users of the project to add whatever Qt location themselves, while still being able to have "more than one" Qt location.**

You may request the users to pass the Qt path as a parameter (when calling CMake through the command line)

```
cmake -DQT_PATH={PATH TO QT} ...
```

Or read an environment variable (which the user would have to set)

```
if(DEFINED ENV{QT_ENVIRON})
    set(QT_PATH $ENV{QT_ENVIRON})
else()
    set(QT_PATH ...)
endif()
```

Comment: That seems crazy lol? How do people constantly testing for multiple platforms cope? There must be a way?